# Time series analysis with seasonality. Any such statistical/machine learning java library available?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, weka, forecasting, trend

I need a forecasting model that will use time series as well as seasonality. Example, to predict Feb 2013 data, I will use Jan 2013 data and Feb 2012 data.

I was trying to assess TripleExponentialSmoothing and SVM (as used in the Weka forecasting library). However, with limited statistical prowess, I am not sure what(and probably how) to leverage.

I need this as a part of an enterprise Java application. Is there a Java library that I could use?

Comment: I see the question has been voted down. My apologies if this is unclear. If someone can atleast confirm whether I am thinking in the right direction that would be enough.

Comment: Triple Exponential Smoothing (if I remember correct, it's the version with seasonality) is actually very easy to code (at most 30 lines of `python`. Why not just implement it yourself? :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog)  with Time [Series Predication](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Workbench_Time-Series_Example).

Once you have learned the concept of time series prediction with Encog, using weka and SVM will be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `WEKA` is not the best tool for that stuff. You can use `R` from `Java` through `JRI`: http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/JRI/

Here is a small and quick tutorial about time-series analysis in `R`: http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/105815/Time-series-analysis-using-R-for-cost-forecasting-models-in-8-steps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe using R has a learning curve in itself. I had assessed RJava initially. If I am not mistaken, it is basically a JNI bridge for connecting to R instance from java. Thus I need to know R scripting for that, which unfortunately isn't my forte.